# no log file from cronjob

Tags: bash, cron, log

I need to write a script to periodically upgrade the system , I created this test script that does that every 2 mins to check whether it works, however if I run the script and after some time check the /var/log directory there is no my .log file there . I checked crontab -l and it shows the newly added cronjob. 
What can be the problem and what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

log_dir=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
crontab -l > mycron
#echo new cron into cron file
echo "*/2 * * * * (sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade) >> /var/log/update-$log_dir.log 2>&1" >> mycron
#install new cron file
crontab mycron
rm mycron
```

Comment: It's probably about permissions.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are doing. Are you trying to add a new cronjob every 2 minutes ? Or do you just run the script above once ?

Comment: I run it once and it adds a cronjob but the log file is missing.

Comment: tried that, didn't make a difference

Comment: I found out , the issue is in permissions

Comment: If you sudoers file is not correct, `sudo apt-get -y update` will ask for a password.

Comment: Instead of using `sudo` in crontab, you should use root’s crontab for the commands to be executed as root. And why are you not using [unattended-upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates) actually?

Comment: Thanks, root's crontab really solved it! It is an internship task I was given and it just needed to be done via shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `sudo` in a crontab. To run a command as another user using cron, edit the crontab for that user. In the root’s crontab, you could just run `apt-get` commands without `sudo`.

To edit root’s crontab, use:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

(I wouldn’t make a script to add a line to crontab as it is a one-time job not worth automating it.)